# WCF Casting inquery

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying WCF for the first time and I have a service running which I'm trying to implement on a client program.  The client program is another program I had running.

One of my functions begins with this

```
public DataTable RunStoredProcWithDataTable(string storedprocname, List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> paramlist)
```

In the client program, I have the WCF loaded as a web reference labeled as "Service".  If I try to implement this function in the client program, the function is expecting "Service.SqlParameter" where "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter" is expected.

I tried converting the SqlClient.SqlParameter to Service.SqlParameter by casting it.

```
paramlist = (List<DataAccessService.SqlParameter>)paramlist;
```

Gets me the error "Cannot convert type List < SqlClient.SqlParameter> to List < Service.SqlParameter>"

Is there a way to get to to convert without me fishing through the code and changing SqlClisnt.SqlParameter to Service.SqlParameter?

This is the Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface ISqlAccess
{
 [OperationContract]
 DataTable RunStoredProcWithDataTableParameter(SqlAccess sql, string storedprocname, List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> paramlist);
}
```

This is the Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class SqlAccess
{
    [DataMember]
    public string connectionname;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a bit more detail regarding the service and operation contract ...

Comment: alright.  I'll add more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a function that just converted it from the normal SqlParameter to the new Sql Parameter.

This is the function I used

```
private DataAccessService.DataAccessSqlParameter ConvertParam(SqlParameter param)
{
    DataAccessService.DataAccessSqlParameter daparam = new DataAccessService.DataAccessSqlParameter();
    daparam.ParameterName = param.ParameterName;
    daparam.ParameterValue = param.Value;
    return daparam;
}
```